# error in my c sharp code, error with Console.ReadLine?

Tags: c#

I'm completely new to c# and have learned that the code

```
var result = "Apples" != "Oranges";
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

would give a result of 'true', but the output wouldn't show up and for that I learned that you needed to use the `Console.ReadLine`.
Though, I got an error: CS0201  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement and don't know what the problem is, does anyone have an answer?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = "Apples" != "Oranges";
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `Console.ReadLine();` instead of `Console.ReadLine;`? [Console.ReadLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2):

change

```
Console.ReadLine;
```

to

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

As crashmstr said, you need to put Console.ReadLine(); as a method call in your line. Otherwise, the compiler is confused what you're trying to do with the ReadLine method. Method's require ().